# select id from table where this colum exist in another table as a name

Tags: php, mysql, sql

This is how my tables looks like

```
Table 1 
id    topic    authors_id
1     test     2
2     test2    1
3     test3    4
4     test4    3

Table 2
id    author
1     name1
2     name2
3     name3
4     name4
```

Is there a way to select authors_id from table one and show it as author from table2 ?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you want an SQL inner join

```
select table1.authors_id,
    table2.author
from table1
inner join table2 on table1.authors_id = table2.author
```